# Open PDF from iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, ios6

I am developing an app where I create a PDF in the app and have to open it, so that the user can view it. I know that we can use Webview to open any PDF, but I want to open the PDF in the iPhones default PDF viewer(THE ONE WHICH OPENS UP WHEN WE CLICK ANY ATTACHED PDF IN EMAIL) which has share button on right side of the navigation bar and a back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is use the QuickLook framework and this is what the mail client uses (or close to it). It has a pdf viewer and it is really simple to use so I will direct you to the apple docs :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your quick reply.This is what I was looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample code in the following link and it will help u 100 %.

http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/17/load-a-pdf-file-in-the-iphone-app-smoothly/